# GLSL webgl lerp normals from uv offset

Tags: three.js, glsl, webgl, shader, vertex-shader

I have a displacement map on a plane 512px* 512px (100x100 segments) , as the image for the displacement map scrolls left the vertices snap to position of height not blend smoothly, I have been looking at the mix() function and smooth-step() to morph the normals to their positions over time but i having a hard time implementing it.

```
    uniform sampler2D heightText;  //texture greyscale 512x512
    uniform float displace;        
    uniform float time;
    uniform float speed;

    varying vec2 vUV;
    varying float scaleDisplace;

    void main() { 
        vUV = uv;
        vec2 uvOffset = vUV + vec2( 0.1, 0.1)* time;    // animates offset
        vec2 uvCo = vUV + vec2( 0.0, 0.0);
        vec2 texSize = vec2(-0.8, 0.8);        // scales image larger

        vec4 data = texture2D( heightText, uvOffset + fract(uvCo)*texSize.x);
        scaleDisplace = data.r; 

        //vec3 possy = normal  * displace  * scaleDisplace;

        vec3 morphPossy = mix( position, normal *displace , scaleDisplace)* time ;

        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(morphPossy, 1.0 );


   }
```

Using Three.js 71 with vertex and pixel:

Illustration purpose:

[image: uv offset]
Any help appreciated ...

Comment: Im still looking into this with not much luck, at the moment i am looking at using other complete methods but ideally want to stay with this approach.

Comment: Please reword/elaborate on your question, I have no idea what you mean by "the displacement map scrolls left the vertices snap to position of height".

Comment: @Brendan updated with picture for a visual perspective..

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle to play with? You can include the displacement map as outlined [here](http://blog.2pha.com/using-threejs-jsfiddle)

Comment: i will need a day.... or so

Comment: Not very clear question. But: Is your texture sampled nearest maybe? Also normals need to be re-normalized after blending - but it sounds you worry about offsets - I don't see any normals in your shader?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a texture as a height map, you should make sure that:

```
heightText.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter; // This is the default value.
```

so that the values you receive are smoothed texel to texel.